# Progress developer studio eclipse platform uninstallation

Tags: eclipse-plugin, progress-4gl, openedge

I tried installing Eclipse platform plugin in the progress openedge 11.5.
I didn't liked it and uninstalled the plugin. From then i couldn't open progress developer studio. It is showing a pop up window with a message "The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate it's companion shared library".

Kindly suggest me a solution to overcome this issue ?

Thanks
Santosh Reddy

Comment: What steps did you take to uninstall the Eclipse plugin?  Did you reboot after the uninstall? Clearly the uninstall was not successful. You need to supply additional information if you want help.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you will need to re-install Progress to get this working again. It sounds like uninstalling the plugin has removed something Progress needs to operate.